# Why does Integral constraint require fromIntegral on call to length?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've just started programming in Haskell, and I am solving [99 Haskell problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems), and when I was nearly done with 10th, I've encountered this problem:

```
-- Exercise 9
pack :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack list = let (left,right) = span (== head list) list in
            left : pack right

-- Exercise 10        
encode :: (Eq a, Integral c) => [a] -> [(c, a)]
encode [] = []
encode list = map (\x -> (length x, head x)) (pack list)
-- this doesn't work      ^^^^^^^^
```

The error produced told me that

```
Could not deduce (c ~ Int)
from the context (Eq a, Integral c)
  bound by the type signature for
             encode :: (Eq a, Integral c) => [a] -> [(c, a)]
  at C:\fakepath\ex.hs:6:11-47
  `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        encode :: (Eq a, Integral c) => [a] -> [(c, a)]
      at C:\fakepath\ex.hs:6:11
In the return type of a call of `length'
In the expression: length x
In the expression: (length x, head x)
```

I've managed to fix that by inserting a function I've read about in [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com): `fromIntegral`.

```
encode list = map (\x -> (fromIntegral $ length x, head x)) (pack list)
```

So, my question is, **why is that needed**?

I've run `:t length` and got `[a] -> Int`, which is a pretty defined type for me, which should satisfy `Integral c` constraint.

Comment: Just a hint: I don’t think you need the `encode [] = []` case, as `pack [] = []` and `map _ [] = []`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type signature `(Eq a, Integral c) => [a] -> [(c, a)]` means the function works for *any* types `a` and `c` in the appropriate typeclasses. The actual type used is specified at the call site.

As a simple example, let's take a look at the type of the empty list:

```
:t []
[a]
```

What this means is that `[]` represents an empty list of `String`, and empty list of `Int`, an empty list of `Maybe [Maybe Bool]` and whatever other types you can imagine. We can imagine wrapping this in a normal identifier:

```
empty :: [a]
empty = []
```

`empty` obviously works the same way as `[]`. So you can see that the following definition would make no sense:

```
empty :: [a]
empty = [True]
```

after all, `[True]` can never be a `[Int]` or `[String]` or whatever other empty list you want.

The idea here is the same, except we have typeclass constraints on the variables as well. For example, you can use `encode` to return a `[(Integer, String)]` list because `Integer` is also in the `Integral` class.

So you have to return something polymorphic that could be *any* `Integral`--just what `fromIntegral` does. If you just returned `Int`, `encode` would only be usable as an `Int` and not any `Integral`.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Would you care to solve my last concern here, though, being "Should I then leave it with `fromIntegral` or should I simply specify it as `encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]`? *Now that I know*, both approaches look OK, but I would personally lean towards simpler `Int`.

Comment: I would keep the `fromIntegral`--I find dealing with `Int` and periodically having to cast annoying. Another option is to use `genericLength` from `Data.List`.